# Cordova Application in Emulator throws "HelloMap won't run unless you update Google Play Services" although GPS are installed

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, android-emulator, google-play-services

I installed fallowing things with Android Studio SDK Manager:

- Intel x86 Google API System Image [API level 23]
- Google API

I create **Virtual Device** with **Target** `Android 6.0 (Google APIs)`

**Problem:**

If I run sample [HelloMap](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Tutorial-for-Mac) app, app alerts me:

[image: application alert]

Why? If I look to `Settings -> Apps -> Google Play Services`, it's enabled  **(v9.0.80)**

Maybe gradle.build will be helpful:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

**EDIT:**

from **adb logcat** i get this:

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9256000 but found 9080470
```

now is clear, that i have lower version of Google Play Services, than System image requires. Problem is that GPS are up to date according to SDK manager in Android Studio.

[Relevant thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106075/firebase-auth-not-working-update-google-play-services-msg-on-the-emulator-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not trying to run the sample HelloMap app, but I did encounter this error after building one of my apps using an updated Android SDK.

I changed plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/plugin.xml to:

```
46         <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2" />
47         <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2" />
```

After that I removed and re added the android platform it started working on the emulator.

I found some info at:
[Firebase Auth not working - 'Update Google Play services' msg on the emulator (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106075/firebase-auth-not-working-update-google-play-services-msg-on-the-emulator-a)
and  http://notnull.co/2016/06/16/android-issues-this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services/

Comment: This seems to be fixed with the latest Google APIs system images

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, seems to be a bug when you upgrade your google services but the android emulator doesn't reflect the change.

So, you should go back, 9.0.2 it's fine.