# What is the causes of the RuntimeException of firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got a crash report on my Google developer console, I'm use firebase database in my app.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.abdalltif.wajabatonline.WajabatOnlineApp: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.internal.ym: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4733)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.internal.ym: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.m.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ay.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ed.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.et.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.fs.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.fs.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.k.d(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.k.b(Unknown Source)
at com.abdalltif.wajabatonline.WajabatOnlineApp.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4730)
... 10 more
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.internal.ym: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ye.a(Unknown Source)
... 22 more
```

What is the problem?
Is it in my android code or from firebase?

Comment: Possibly caused by missing or out-dated version of Google Play Services.  In your code, do you check that a suitable version of Play Services is installed by calling `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()`?

Comment: Little tips, you should focus on `"No acceptable module found"` more than `"RuntimeException"`. I think @BobSnyder is right, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38251934/4112725) might help you

Comment: No, I'm not checking it, I'll try it