# Google Play Services crashes as soon as I update it

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, simulation, genymotion

I am using Genymotion (2.7.0) to test my Android app, developed in Android studio. I'm simulating a Samsung Galaxy S5-4.4.4. My app requires Google Play Services in order to run properly,, so I followed the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su) to install it on the genymotion device. However, as soon as I update Google Play Services, I constantly get the pop up windows "Unfortunately Google Play Services Has Stopped" and "unfortunately the process com.google.process.gapps has stopped" Whenever I click on anything in the phone. Trying to go to the Google Play Store just tells me that something's gone wrong and I need to sign in again (but I can't because of the previously mentioned bugs.) If I uninstall the updates to Google Play Services these pop ups stop, but then my app can't run properly.

What should I do?

EDIT: I've tried using other Genymotion devices, I've tried reinstalling genymotion, and I've tried clearing all data/caches for both Google Services and Google Service Framework. None of this has worked and I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: see if this help . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106075/firebase-auth-not-working-update-google-play-services-msg-on-the-emulator-a/38233586#38233586

Comment: But the errors aren't just happening when i go into my app, it's happening all the time whenever I try to interact with any Google-related app.

Comment: have you try use the AVD from Android Studio ? they are really good and fast now , my ADV come up in 10 seconds only and it install the apk quickly too

Comment: I have an AMD processor so it doesn't work on my PC.

Comment: if you are using Linux i think you can run it , sorry i not using GenyMotion for over a year .

Comment: Nah since I don't have the Intel Emulator Accelerator I get 'emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3'

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [blog](http://www.problogbooster.com/2015/12/unfortunately-google-play-services-has.html), you can fix the error **"Unfortunately Google Play Services Has Stopped"** by reset Google Play Services cache CACHE & UPDATES. The Google Play Services app in your phone acts like a framework for all the Google and Google Play apps installed in your phone.

- *Go to Settings >> Application Manager >> All >> Google Play Store >> clear cache & uninstall updates. Reboot device.*

Try also to clear the Google Services Framework cache. The Google Services Framework system app on your Android device stores information and helps your phone sync with Google servers; and keeps your Google Play Services up and running.

- *Go to Settings >> Application Manager >> All >> Google Services Framework >> click "Force stop" & tap on the "Clear cache" button. Reboot device.*

Error **"Unfortunately the process com.google.process.gapps has stopped"** also occurs when the app is unable to connect to servers, has timed out or is not in sync. You can also fix it by restarting Google Framework Services as stated in this [link](http://appuals.com/fix-google-process-gapps/).

Check these related issues:

- [How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su)
- [Google Play Services Has stopped message continually popping up on my Samsung phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/122918/google-play-services-has-stopped-message-continually-popping-up-on-my-samsung-ph)

Comment: Neither of these worked for me. I still get about a dozen pop up notifications telling me how various google applications and services have stopped working every few seconds. Ironically 'Solution 1' in your second related issues link is what's causing my problem. When I have the outdated Google Services, there are no crashes, I just can't run my app. Once I update Google Services is when I start running into so many problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing repeated issues of Google Play Service crashes, here is a simple method to resolve this issue.
Steps to Follow:

1. Go to Settings menu.
2. Click on option APPS and select Google Play Services.
3. Under info. Click on "Uninstall Updates".
4. Make sure your security software is OFF.
5. Try running YouTube & it will ask to Update "Google Play Service".
6. Update it and run YouTube again.
7. Check back, problem is Solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my device running on android 10.

I did some research and found [here](https://droidtheory.com/fix-google-play-store-download-pending/) that uninstalling updates of the app and clearing cache and data can help in fixing this issue. I tried these steps on my device and it works fine now.

Otherwise I was also facing play store not downloading and play store crashing issue.

Also try updating your OS version to latest one for more stable performance.