# Google Play-Services do not update - What can I do?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

in my Android Studio Project I use Firebase for Cloud-Messaging.
This need Play-Services so I did following:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.0'`

`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'`

But I always get this error:

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.
>       Requires 9080000 but found 8489032

Maybe someone can help me?
Thank you:)

Comment: Device or Emulator??

Comment: If running on an emulator, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38108259/4815718

Comment: thanks:) but I have this Problem on Device:/