# firebase authentication error - "update google play services"

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-authentication

I have project with Firebase from google. First I done simple chat activity - only sending messages with this database. Everything worked fine. But now I'd like to add another activity with authentication via email/password. In the same project on the same database and android emulator now I get message:

> "Update Google Play services : ChatApp won't run unless you update Google Play services"

I looked around on both Google and StackOverflow past few hours and have found some information. However, I have not got it to work.

I created Nexus 5X emulator with API 25 and Target: Android 7.1.1(Google APIs) x86 and second Nexus 6 with CPU/ABI x86_64. Google Play services on both are in version: 9.8.79 and I use auth in version 10.0.1. I try to create new emulators, I updated everything as [here was said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106075/firebase-auth-not-working-update-google-play-services-msg-on-the-emulator-a) I changed in Firebase settings ability to log via e-mail.

Really makes me wonder why everything worked previously and now with authentication is not.

I'm relatively inexperienced in Android development.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You try in emulator and try in physical device?

Comment: No. Only emulator I dont have access to android mobile device.

Comment: There is no released emulator image for API 25 that supports Firebase Auth 10.0.1.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41104004/4815718).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing (Jan 20, 2017) the API level 25 emulators have a fairly version of Play services.  If you want to use the latest client library version 10.0.1, you should use an emulator image that targets API level 24 instead.

The general rule is that the version of Play services on the device should be greater than or equal to the version of the client libraries you want to use.  Therefore, the version 9.8.79 you see on the API level 25 emulators won't work with 10.0.1 client libraries. However, version 10.0.84 of Play services available on API level 24 should work fine.

The version of Play services available for emulators only updates when you there is a tooling update.  There isn't a Google-sanctioned way of updating an existing emulator image with a new version of Play.